# Issue connecting two Extreme Networks 220 series switches together, with only one VLAN

Tags: switch, extreme

I am in the AV field, which as a lot of IT folk know is becoming a lot closer with IT, but my networking knowledge is limited aside from the basics.

We have a system in place with AV over IP devices, Crestron NVX to be exact. Currently there are multiple stand alone systems each with their own Extreme Networks switch, but we are trying to connect these rooms together, so that the video feed from a specific NVX device can be viewed remotely from each room. These switches currently do not connect to anything else besides endpoint devices, no internet access, etc.

Right now I have only two switches connected. All devices connected to these switches are assigned static IPs. The only VLAN on each of these switches is the default VLAN 1. My thought process was that since everything was on the same VLAN things would just work when two switches were plugged in together. I do get connectivity, but when I am plugged into one switch accessing devices on the far-side switch doesn't go as I would expect.

For example, the NVX units have a HTTPS Browser config page. When I try to access this the page will continuously load and not get to the log in page. I pulled up wireshark and see a lot of TLS stuff going on, and being repeated. Devices on the far side that have non secure HTTP configuration pages seem to pull up fine. Pings to devices on the far side also seem to be inconsistent too, as they will just not respond, not respond on the first request, or just respond fine.

I didn't have a lot of time to play with this, but wanted to see if anyone had any suggestion on what I should check/do before I am able to get back on site and screw around with this.

**Edit:** All IPs are on the same subnet, they are all 192.168.1.x. There are no conflicts, static IPs were assigned with this in mind for the future.

**Edit 2:** So I am on site today and not able to get to the original switch currently I was working with prior, so I am using another rooms switch. I think there is something to do with the multicast traffic from the nvx bogging down the connection from the two rooms. I unplugged all devices from the local switch and I am able to connect find to devices on the other end. The NVX units use a lot of bandwidth when transmitting a stream, but I will have to figure out why there are issues when a stream isn't being transmitted also. I posted the config below of the switch. I checked line by line and each switch is the same apart from addresses, so I figured I'd just post one. There isn't much going on aside from the IGMP stuff.

Also, as for testing with IGMP turned off. These NVX units will flood every port. If transmitting a 4k stream they can saturate a 1gb connection. I've accidentally done this before and locked up some equipment and had to hard reboot it because the multicast streams are just getting sent to everything. I have my devices set to 400mbps max as we only have the 1gb connection and there will only ever be one stream traveling across switches at a time. It makes me wonder if something isn't translating right on the links between switches though and this is causing issues. I will probably contact the manufacturer for suggestions since I know communication between the two switches is working fine now.

```
network protocol none
network parms 192.168.2.4 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.254
serviceport protocol none
serviceport ip 192.168.1.4 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
vlan database
set igmp 1
set igmp fast-leave 1
set igmp querier 1
set igmp querier 1 address 1.1.1.4
set igmp querier election participate 1
exit
ip ssh server enable
configure
stack
member 1 4
exit
slot 1/0 4
set slot power 1/0
no set slot disable 1/0
username "admin" password abdedda536bdf4a771a7543d2f31f39ed317b7490825af6a52f0cef9251e7574fdf8d09b20feb4efb004907bcaa6afd7cc0e3a2a1cb8366584541742667b0d21 level 15 encrypted
line console
exit
line telnet
exit
line ssh
exit
!
set igmp
set igmp querier
set igmp querier address 1.1.1.4
interface 1/0/1
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/2
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/3
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/4
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/5
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/6
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/7
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/8
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/9
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/10
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/11
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/12
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/13
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/14
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/15
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/16
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/17
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/18
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/19
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/20
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/21
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/22
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/23
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/24
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/25
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface 1/0/26
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 1
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 2
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 3
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 4
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 5
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
interface lag 6
set igmp
set igmp fast-leave
exit
router rip
exit
exit
```

Comment: We need to see more information in order to help you.  My first question: Are all the A/V devices in the same IP subnet?  Are there overlapping IP addresses?

Comment: I guess that's two questions.

Comment: Added to my initial post, but yes all on the same subnet and no overlapping IPs. The only thing done to these switches from the factory state was enabling IGMP snooping and querying as that is needed for the NVX to work properly. I don't think that would affect connectivity between the two switches, but probably worth mentioning.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configuration of both switches.  Use the preformatted text option { } .

Comment: Good idea. I will not be able to pull that off until tomorrow but I will add it here.

Comment: This shouldn't affect the HTTPS sessions, but it's suspect that the NVX gear "requires" IGMP snooping and an MROUTER.  I'd consider that advice incorrect for a small-scale deployment, and leave IGMP snooping disabled while you're troubleshooting; then enable it as a discrete step once your prototype setup is working to see if it causes any ill effects.

Comment: This sounds like a multicast issue, if I understood the setup correctly, it works when everything is connected to the same switch, but not when you have two interconnected switches?

Comment: Yeah I'm think it's a multicast issue now too. I have 3 switches connected right now. I can communicate from Switch A to B and B to C. But A to C is extremely slow to the point nothing on that switch can be accessed.